# Extend/Collapse Html row and sum rows content jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table

Could any one please correct me this code, so when I click pro - the rows : task 1, 2, 3 collapse, and if possible show the sum of numbers.

```
<table border="0">
<tr>
    <td rowspan="3" colspan="1" class="header">pro <span>-</span> </td>
    <td rowspan="1" style="text-align:center; height : 100%;">task 1</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height:100%; text-align:center;">
    <td rowspan="1" style="text-align:center; height : 100%;">task 2</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height:100%; text-align:center;">
    <td rowspan="1" style="text-align:center; height : 100%;">task3</td>
</tr>
```

the jQuery code :

```
$('.header').click(function(){
$(this).find('span').text(function(_, value){return value=='-'?'+':'-'});
$(this).nextUntil('tr.header').slideToggle(100); // or just use "toggle()"});
```

Comment: No, its not neccessary, to get the result i want, see on the demo, the first colum , have to span 3 line of the second colum, the html is not a problem, but the jquery code on web site enclosed

Comment: What have you tried to accomplish this? Can you post any jQuery/javascript code you have?

Comment: Sum of what numbers? Can you share the code you have till now?

Comment: Sorry the link i provided was not working here is the jquery code, the  numbers after task, 1+2+3